# Hiding the element in react not working on the basis of state value

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to toggle a div on the basis of a click on button , the issue is I have kept the state false in constructor

```
class  App extends Component {
constructor(props){
super(props);
this.flipScreen = this.flipScreen.bind(this);

this.state = {
   hideDashBoard: false,
   hideContractScreen:true,
 }
}
}
```

the html in render function

```
 <div  className={this.state.hideContractScreen ? 'hidden' : ''} style = {{position:"absolute",left:"250px",top:"50px"}}class="row">
```

still the element is displayed when the web page is loaded first

Comment: What is inside of your `.hidden` class?

Comment: .hidden{
  display: none;
}